# Main stress in 'person specifications'

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

> They use job descriptions and person specifications.

What this sentence means and whether it's logical is beyond the point.

**My question is the following:** What happens to the stress in the word 'specifications'? Does it move back to the front of the word?

I can't find the rule for the 'noun + longer noun' pattern i.e. for words with a main and secondary stress.
[image]

> 'PErson(noun) 'specifiˌcations (longer noun)

OR

> 'PErson(noun) ˌspecifi'cations (longer noun)

OR

> 'person(noun) 'SPEcifiˌcations (longer noun)

I'm talking about the phrase 'person specifications' employed in a coherent sentence where I'm providing new information to the speaker without any emphasis on any specific words. Which one is the correct version? I wouldn't mind some link or screenshot to back up your claims, but if it can't be provided, then by all means tell me what's your take on this.

Comment: The emphasis isn't any different than the individual words. (The phrase "person specifications" doesn't really make sense.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_specification

Comment: Very interesting - I'd never heard of a "person specification" before either.  I notice all of the references for the Wiki page are UK websites; I wonder if it's primarily a British English term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Person Specification** is British English, but more importantly it is a *specialized term* (or *industry phrase*) so the rule you are referencing will not apply.

Intuitively, I place the stress on ***PER***son and  *specifi**CA**tion*.